# How to remove Bluetooth 2 - 3 second delay?

Tags: headphones, bluetooth-audio

I have noticed an ~3 second delay when using Bluetooth in my vehicle ([rabbit hole](https://www.wranglerforum.com/f274/uconnect-bluetooth-and-cell-phone-issues-1155673.html)) with a stock head unit and UConnect.  Apparently it's a common problem and the dealer(s) admits to it, and the problem is the specific model of the UConnect device, not just the head unit.  Newer units in other vehicles don't have this issue.  Ok, fine whatevs.

However, today I noticed the same phenomenon with my Bluetooth headphones ([SX-991's like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0768R43B5)).  I'm not sure if the problem came up when I downgraded to Android 5.1 to OctOS L, the [volume boosting app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodev.volume.booster&hl=en_US) I use, or some other app or setting.  These headphones used to work fine without lag.  However, I haven't used them much in the past few months, so I'm not sure when the problem arose.  I have used the headphones without issue after downgrading, but I don't recallt he last time I used them.

In doing a bit of research, it seems that [Honda Civics](https://www.9thgencivic.com/forum/audio-video-navigation/100729-android-3-second-bluetooth-sound-delay-print.html) and [some Mazdas](https://www.reddit.com/r/mazda3/comments/5lu1um/is_there_a_fix_for_bluetooth_audio_delaylag/) have had this problem as well, but that goes back to headunits and possibly UConnect.

What can I do to remove this ~3 seconds of lag for the headphones?  It makes watching a video with the headset unplayable.  Most other pages I find discussing this problem complain about fractions of a second, not several seconds, also usually in reference to Netflix and YouTube.  Interestingly, a lot of people say iOS devices do not have this problem.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145935/get-rid-of-0-5s-latency-when-playing-audio-over-bluetooth-with-a2dp) is a very similar question, albeit for Ubuntu and not Android, so I can't really make use of its answers.

Comment: Just to be clear, its when you are playing movies using which app? Problem when using headset/speakerphone on a call?

Comment: Today it was NewPipe, a FOSS YouTube mobile web client.  I also noticed the issue with UConnect when using Pandora and DoggCatcher.  The calls are all real time on the UConnect.  I didn't try a call with the headset today, but I would expect it to also be real time.

Comment: Not a solution, but [VLC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc&hl=en_US)  does have [adjustable audio delay](https://www.vlchelp.com/android-app-sync-audio-adjust-delay/). Unfortunately setting are per video and I believe are the same if you are on built-in speaker or headset.